# bound for the ratio of Gamma functions

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

Let $x \in R$, $N$ is a natural number.

How to bound from above
$$
\frac{\Gamma(1-1/x)}{\Gamma(N+1-1/x)}
$$

Comment: This ratio is exactly $$\big( (N-1/x)(N-1-1/x) \cdots (1-1/x) \big)^{-1},$$ by the [functional equation for the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition).

Comment: If $x$ is any real number, $1/x$ is any real number except zero. It could be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated application of the fact that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\cdot\Gamma(x) \text{ for } x\notin-\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ yields
$$\frac{\Gamma(1-1/x)}{\Gamma(N+1-1/x)}=\prod_{i=1}^N \,\left(i-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-1}$$
Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

When $x\to 1^+$, then
$$
\frac{\Gamma(1-1/x)}{\Gamma(N+1-1/x)} \sim \frac{1}{(N-1)!} \frac{x}{x-1} \underset{x\to 1^+}{\longrightarrow} +\infty
$$
so it cannot be bounded above.